# Broken Backward Compatibility in System.Web.Http

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a situation where I have some code in a client app that used `System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostServer` in an assembly that targets .net4.0 as a result the dependency is on v4.0.0.0 of `System.Web.Http.dll`

I also have some other code on a server that is a webApi, targetting .net4.6.1.  This assembly has a dependency on `System.Web.Htpp.dll` v5.2.3

Everything runs fine.

But then I come to write an automated integration test (as a unit test) in which the process needs to instantiate both parts of the system (without the scaffolding of IIS or the likes).  The unit test assembly is necessarily .net4.6.1 (as it has a dependency on the server side assemblies).  This means that the reference to `System.Web.Http` in the unit test assembly brings v5.2.3 into its bin folder.

At runtime this results in a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` with the `LoaderException`

```
"{"Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostConfiguration'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.":"System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostConfiguration"}"
```

in my app.config (for the unit test assembly) I have a runtime rediect:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

which means my .net4 dependency is forced to use the v5.2.3 of System.Web.Http.

Without this runtime redirect the client side assemblies complain about a missing dependency (`System.Web.Http` v4.0.0.0), and if I  have v4.0.0.0 of `System.Web.Http` in the bin directory (but not v5.2.3) then the server side assemblies complain about the missing dependency.

Is there any way I can get around this problem?  To me it looks like `System.Web.Http` v5.2.3 is not backward compatible.

[image]

Comment: Why not separate the unit test projects?

Comment: There is only one unit test project. The unit (integration test) instantiates a client and server then proceeds to invoke some functionality of one or other of these and asserts that everything happens as expected.  The code for the server and client (production code) is in 2 separate assemblies, the unit tests in a third that references both. Sorry if that was not clear

Comment: Why not instantiate the server in its own process? Even if you did manage to work around it, your integration test would no longer be representative of what actually happens, since the real server and the real client use different code. Being representative is probably the most important part of an integration test. Obviously, doing input/output tests is more involved if your server runs in its own process since you can't peek directly into its brain, but, again, this is supposed to be an integration test.

Comment: Yes, integration test may be the wrong term.  What I am trying to achieve is more of an end to end extended unit test.  I have mocked out database connections, I am validating the calls to the databases, I have mocked out the httpClients that make calls between services, intercept any calls and route them using the test setup and I validate that the result at the end is as expected given the known input.  In other words I need to peek directly into all stages of the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a lot simpler than it looked above.  The client side code was the one using the `System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostServer` so as a result it was pulling the assembly `System.Web.Http.SelfHost.dll` into the bin directory.

The unit tests assembly was pulling in `System.Web.Http.dll` as both it and the server side required it.

The selfhost dll was v4.0.0.0 and the system.web.http was v5.2.3.  This is where the problem came from.  The fix was to ensure v5.2.3 of `System.Web.Http.SelfHost.dll` was in the bin directory and add a redirect to the app.config of the unit test assembly.